# Understanding LSTM units vs. cells

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow

I have been studying LSTMs for a while. I understand at a high level how everything works. However, going to implement them using Tensorflow I've noticed that [BasicLSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cells_for_use_with_tensorflow_s_core_rnn_methods#BasicLSTMCell) requires a *number of units* (i.e. `num_units`) parameter.

From [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) very thorough explanation of LSTMs, I've gathered that a single *LSTM unit* is one of the following

[image: LSTM unit]

which is actually a GRU unit.

I assume that parameter `num_units` of the `BasicLSTMCell` is referring to how 
many of these we want to hook up to each other in a layer.

That leaves the question - what is a "cell" in this context? Is a "cell" equivalent to a layer in a normal feed-forward neural network?

Comment: I am still confused, I was reading http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ and I understand that well. How does the term cell apply with respect to that article? It seems that an LSTM cell in the article is a vector as in Tensorflow, right?

Comment: That units in Keras is the dimension of the output space, which is equal to the length of the delay (time_step) the network is recurring to. keras.layers.LSTM(units, activation='tanh', ....) https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The terminology is unfortunately inconsistent. `num_units` in TensorFlow is the number of hidden states, i.e. the dimension of $h_t$ in the equations you gave.

Also, from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard9/tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell.md :

> The definition of cell in this package differs from the definition used in the literature. In the literature, cell refers to an object with a single scalar output. The definition in this package refers to a horizontal array of such units.

"LSTM layer" is probably more explicit, [example](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/lstm.py):

```
def lstm_layer(tparams, state_below, options, prefix='lstm', mask=None):
    nsteps = state_below.shape[0]
    if state_below.ndim == 3:
        n_samples = state_below.shape[1]
    else:
        n_samples = 1

    assert mask is not None
    […]
```

Comment: Ah I see, so then a "cell" is a `num_unit` sized horizontal array of interconnected LSTM cells. Makes sense. So then it would be analogous to a hidden layer in a standard feed-forward network then?

Comment: *LSTM state units

Comment: @rec That's correct

Comment: Excellent, I'll go ahead and mark this solved. Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of "horizontal" (perhaps in contrast to "vertical")? I think I understand from your answer that if num_unit=2 means that there are two separate LSTM progressions for each input (each with its own memory state and weight parameters) producing two separate outputs. (By "separate" I mean that  only inputs, but not parameters, weights or hidden states, are shared between them.)

Comment: @Sycorax for example, if the input of the neural network is a timeseries with 10 time steps, the horizontal dimension has 10 elements.

Comment: Are those 10 time-steps `num_units`? Or something else? I have this same question about TensorFlow but it's still a bit opaque to me.

Comment: @Sycorax in the diagram the OP gave, there would be $x_1, … , x_{10}$ inputs, and $h_1, …, h_{\text{num_units}}$ hidden states for each input.

Comment: I am still confused, I was reading http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ and I understand that well. How does the term cell apply with respect to that article? It seems that an LSTM cell in the article is a vector as in Tensorflow, right?

Answer (score 14):

Most LSTM/RNN diagrams just show the hidden cells but never the units of those cells. Hence, the confusion. 
Each hidden layer has hidden cells, as many as the number of time steps.
And further, each hidden cell is made up of multiple hidden units, like in the diagram below. Therefore, the dimensionality of a hidden layer matrix in RNN is (number of time steps, number of hidden units).

[image]

Comment: Seems confusing. So, what's in the diagram? A hidden cell that has multiple hidden units? But you just said hidden cells are correlated with time steps. Ah, I am confused as well.

Comment: The LSTM layer in the diagram has 1 cell and 4 hidden units. The diagram also shows that Xt is size 4. It is coincidental that # hidden units = size of Xt. Xt can be any size. Importantly, there are NOT 3 LSTM cells. The diagram is just trying to illustrate the sequential dependency of the inputs and outputs of the one LSTM cell.

Comment: So the 4 "cells" in each of the x values, are they different parameters, eg. temperature, humidity? If this was a language model where each x value was a word, would we only have 1 circle at each x time step?

Answer (score 7):

Although the issue is almost the same as I answered in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/275518/103153), I'd like to illustrate this issue, which also confused me a bit today in the seq2seq model (thanks to @Franck Dernoncourt's answer), in the graph. In this simple encoder diagram:

[image]

Each $h_i$ above is the same cell in different time-step (cell either GRU or LSTM as that in your question) and the weight vectors(not bias) in the cell are of the same size of (num_units/[num_hidden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/textsum/seq2seq_attention_model.py#L162) or [state_size or output_size](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L438-L444)).

RNN is a special type of graphical model where nodes form a directed list as explained in section 4 of this paper: [Supervised Neural Networks for the Classication of Structures](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3e33/eca03933caaec671e20692e79d1acc9527e1.pdf?_ga=2.39417827.1171729834.1582275392-1665748241.1567748058#page=7). We can think of `num_units` as the number of tags in CRF(although CRF is undirected), and the matrices($W$'s in graph in the question) are all shared across all time steps like the transition matrix in CRF.

Comment: I believe the `num_units = n` in this figure

Comment: @notilas No, please don't. num_units is the dimension of the $h_i$.

Answer (score 4):

In `keras.layers.LSTM(units, activation='tanh', ....)`, the `units` refers to the *dimensionality* or *length of the hidden state* or the *length of the activation vector* passed on the next LSTM cell/unit - the next LSTM cell/unit is the "green picture above with the gates etc from http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

The *next LSTM cell/unit* (i.e. the green box with gates etc from http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) is NOT the same as the `units` in `keras.layers.LSTM(units, activation='tanh', ....)`

The `units` are also sometimes called the `latent dimensions`. Here is a detailed explanation of the `units` LSTM parameter:

https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/58854907

Comment: Thank you. Your last link has the clearest explanation I've seen thus far. I held many of the same misconceptions that the author clears up.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, cell means a node such as hidden cell which is also called hidden node, for multilayer LSTM model,the number of cell can be computed by time_steps*num_layers, and the num_units is equal to time_steps

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [TF's tutorial on RNNs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn):

> In addition to the built-in RNN layers, the RNN API also provides cell-level APIs. Unlike RNN layers, which processes whole batches of input sequences, the RNN cell only processes a single timestep.