# What are 'blocks' of an LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

I have read Christopher Olah's excellent LSTM article (I do not have enough reputation to post the link) and found [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179101/structure-of-recurrent-neural-network-lstm-gru?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=1b4c307055084504af12d81910eafbc4) and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241985/understanding-lstm-units-vs-cells). Although I think I understand the mathematics and LSTMs at a high level, I find myself still confused about what exactly LSTM blocks are. What I mean, is that this:

[image: lstm layer]

I know is a layer of an LSTM (across multiple times `t`).

I also know that LSTM networks are made of blocks (or cells, as I've seen them be referred to as):

[image: lstm network]

Finally, blocks are made of units. My question is if layers (first image) exist in a network (second image), what do the 'blocks' of an LSTM look like?

Answer (score 2):

I usually visualize a block as the box (the cup) and the cells as the content.
One block can have one or many cells, but a cell belongs to only one box.

A block controls, protects and manages (through the 3 gates) the information that is held/taken care of by the cells.

I also define one LSTM unit as (one Block + its cells) to avoid getting confused by all the different notations.